# How to create fixed vertical navigation?

Tags: jquery, css, html, menu, modernizr

I'm using a html theme for my website, and I need to add a fixed vertical menu to the left.

I've tried [this tutorial](http://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-fixed-navigation/) for this, ([demo](http://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-fixed-navigation/index.html)), and it uses a modernizr javascript that might not be similar to what I'm using. : [Tutorial Version](http://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-fixed-navigation/js/modernizr.js) of Modernizr, & My [html theme's version](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27854284/Stuff/modernizr.js)

I followed the tutorial, and add only the `NAV` div to my html theme (no `sections`)... I couldn't get the nav to appear as shown on the demo...

EDIT:

I have edited the snippet... now the side-menu is showing, but it's on the right, and with bullets+dots.. Could someone help me out to remove the bullets, and keep only the dots (dark pink dots)... Also, could the menu be placed on the left?

Also, any info on what all components could be removed safely from the css? I'm not sure if all of those components are required... although the menu wasn't showing without this updated css.. I had initially copied the css from the tutorial, only now have I copied the exact contents of the `style.css` from the demo source...

```css
/* -------------------------------- 
 
Primary style
 
-------------------------------- */
html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
 
*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  color: #3e3947;
  background-color: white;
}
 
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
 
a {
  color: #3e3947;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
 
/* -------------------------------- 
 
Modules - reusable parts of our design
 
-------------------------------- */
.cd-img-replace {
  /* replace text with a background-image */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
 
/* -------------------------------- 
 
xnugget info 
 
-------------------------------- */
.cd-nugget-info {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.cd-nugget-info a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #d88683;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-nugget-info a:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}
.cd-nugget-info span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cd-nugget-info span svg {
  display: block;
}
.cd-nugget-info .cd-nugget-info-arrow {
  fill: #d88683;
}
 
/* -------------------------------- 
 
xcarbonads 
 
-------------------------------- */
#carbonads-container {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
#carbonads-container .close-carbon-adv {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-indent: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
#carbonads-container .close-carbon-adv:hover {
  background: #000;
}
#carbonads-container .close-carbon-adv::after, #carbonads-container .close-carbon-adv::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  left: 9px;
}
#carbonads-container .close-carbon-adv::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#carbonads-container .close-carbon-adv::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#carbonads-container .carbonad {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#carbonads-container .carbonad .carbonad-image img {
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
#carbonads-container .carbonad .carbonad-text, #carbonads-container .carbonad .carbonad-tag {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}
#carbonads-container .carbonad .carbonad-text {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
#carbonads-container .carbonad .carbonad-text a {
  color: #d88683;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.no-touch #carbonads-container .carbonad .carbonad-text a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#carbonads-container .carbonad .carbonad-tag {
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #3a393f;
}
#carbonads-container .carbonad .carbonad-tag a {
  color: #3a393f;
}
#carbonads-container .carbonad .carbonad-tag a:hover {
  color: #d88683;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  #carbonads-container {
    display: block;
  }
}
 
/* -------------------------------- 
 
Main components 
 
-------------------------------- */
.cd-section {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2em 0;
}
.cd-section:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #3e3947;
}
.cd-section:nth-of-type(odd) p {
  color: #898099;
}
.cd-section:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #745360;
}
.cd-section:nth-of-type(even) p {
  color: #bda3ad;
}
.cd-section h1, .cd-section p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 768px;
  text-align: center;
}
.cd-section h1 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.cd-section p {
  line-height: 1.6;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-section h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-size: 1.875rem;
  }
  .cd-section p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 2;
  }
}
 
.cd-scroll-down {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 44px;
  background: url("../img/cd-arrow-bottom.svg") no-repeat center center;
}
 
/* No Touch devices */
.cd-nav-trigger {
  display: none;
}
 
.no-touch #cd-vertical-nav {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
.no-touch #cd-vertical-nav li {
  text-align: right;
}
.no-touch #cd-vertical-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  /* prevent weird movements on hover when you use a CSS3 transformation - webkit browsers */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.no-touch #cd-vertical-nav a:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.no-touch #cd-vertical-nav a span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
  -o-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
}
.no-touch #cd-vertical-nav a:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.no-touch #cd-vertical-nav a:hover .cd-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
.no-touch #cd-vertical-nav a.is-selected .cd-dot {
  background-color: white;
}
.no-touch #cd-vertical-nav .cd-dot {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d88683;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.no-touch #cd-vertical-nav .cd-label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: .4em .5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
 
/* Touch devices */
.touch .cd-nav-trigger {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 5%;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.touch .cd-nav-trigger span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #3e3947;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.touch .cd-nav-trigger span::before, .touch .cd-nav-trigger span::after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
.touch .cd-nav-trigger span::before {
  top: -9px;
}
.touch .cd-nav-trigger span::after {
  bottom: -9px;
}
 
.touch #cd-vertical-nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 30px;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
  -moz-transform-origin: right bottom;
  -ms-transform-origin: right bottom;
  -o-transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.touch #cd-vertical-nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(62, 57, 71, 0.1);
}
.touch #cd-vertical-nav a span:first-child {
  display: none;
}
.touch #cd-vertical-nav a.is-selected span:last-child {
  color: #d88683;
}
.touch #cd-vertical-nav.open {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.touch #cd-vertical-nav.open + .cd-nav-trigger {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.touch #cd-vertical-nav.open + .cd-nav-trigger span {
  background-color: rgba(62, 57, 71, 0);
}
.touch #cd-vertical-nav.open + .cd-nav-trigger span::before, .touch #cd-vertical-nav.open + .cd-nav-trigger span::after {
  background-color: #3e3947;
  height: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
  left: -8px;
}
.touch #cd-vertical-nav.open + .cd-nav-trigger span::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 1px;
}
.touch #cd-vertical-nav.open + .cd-nav-trigger span::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  bottom: 0;
}
.touch #cd-vertical-nav li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
 
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .touch .cd-nav-trigger, .touch #cd-vertical-nav {
    bottom: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27854284/Stuff/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="http://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-fixed-navigation/js/main.js"></script>


<nav id="cd-vertical-nav">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#section1" data-number="1">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Intro</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#section2" data-number="2">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">About</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#section3" data-number="3">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Features</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#section4" data-number="4">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Portfolio</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#section5" data-number="5">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Pricing</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#section6" data-number="6">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Contact</span>
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <a class="cd-nav-trigger cd-img-replace">Open navigation<span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here no need to add js ...menu is based on css look my code with example [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3w8guem6/)

```css
body{
background-color:#3E3947;
} 
#cd-vertical-nav {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
#cd-vertical-nav li {
  text-align: right;
  list-style:none;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  /* prevent weird movements on hover when you use a CSS3 transformation - webkit browsers */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
  -o-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:hover .cd-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a.is-selected .cd-dot {
  background-color: white;
}
#cd-vertical-nav .cd-dot {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d88683;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
#cd-vertical-nav .cd-label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: .4em .5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}


/*********************************RIGHT SIDE *************************************/
#cd-vertical-nav_right {
  position: fixed;
  left: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
#cd-vertical-nav_right li {
  text-align: left;
  list-style:none;
}
#cd-vertical-nav_right a {
  display: inline-block;
  /* prevent weird movements on hover when you use a CSS3 transformation - webkit browsers */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cd-vertical-nav_right a:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cd-vertical-nav_right a span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
  -o-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
}
#cd-vertical-nav_right a:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
#cd-vertical-nav_right a:hover .cd-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
#cd-vertical-nav_right a.is-selected .cd-dot {
  background-color: white;
}
#cd-vertical-nav_right .cd-dot {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d88683;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
#cd-vertical-nav_right .cd-label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: .4em .5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="cd-vertical-nav">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a data-number="1" href="#section1" class="is-selected">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Intro</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a data-number="2" href="#section2" class="">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">About</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a data-number="3" href="#section3" class="">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Features</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a data-number="4" href="#section4" class="">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Portfolio</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a data-number="5" href="#section5">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Pricing</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a data-number="6" href="#section6">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Contact</span>
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

<nav id="cd-vertical-nav_right">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a data-number="1" href="#section1" class="is-selected">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Intro</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a data-number="2" href="#section2" class="">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">About</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a data-number="3" href="#section3" class="">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Features</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a data-number="4" href="#section4" class="">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Portfolio</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a data-number="5" href="#section5">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Pricing</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a data-number="6" href="#section6">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">Contact</span>
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer is perfect! Although, you've named the nav_right wrongly... your right nav css is for left, while left nav css is for right... in your answer...

Comment: Could you also provide a way to show some text with the menu? Any code that could show the text? I intend to place a text alongside the menu.... something like SIDE MENU vertically... should I place an image for that or any text too can be placed beside it? ... My page is BOXED styled, so there's some space on the left for this menu.. I need to place some kind of info regarding this menu, cause the page already has a header menu, while this is supposed to be a side menu... Any suggestions?

Comment: thx fot correct my answer,but i cant understand  what is your exact requirement,but for putting image in menu there is various way see link : http://jsfiddle.net/suaswt93/

Comment: That solved the remaining part of the question.. Thanks!

Comment: Hey vrajesh, your answer is correct, but the color of the dots of the menu donot change when we click the dot of a section (or) if we traverse to a section by scrolling up/down. How do you make the color of the dots to change "Dynamically" in the above code?

Comment: That is how to we "Dynamically" change the { class="is-selected" } on the code :-           <li>
    <a data-number="2" href="#section2" class="">
     <span class="cd-dot"></span>
     <span class="cd-label">About</span>
    </a>
   </li>                                                                                           etc etc on the other code sections/ nav sections ??? I guess that would solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function call(){
                var $navLinks = $('#cd-vertical-nav a');
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $navLinks.on('click', function(){
    $navLinks.removeClass('is-selected');
     $(this).addClass('is-selected');
    });

    $('section').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset = $this.offset().top;
    var height = $this.outerHeight();

    if (offset + height <= scrollTop || offset >= scrollTop + (windowHeight - (height / 2))) {
      return;
    }
    
    var selector = '[href="#' + $this.prop('id') + '"]';
    var $menuItem = $navLinks.filter(selector);
      
    $navLinks.removeClass('is-selected');
    $menuItem.addClass('is-selected');
    });
    });

            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
  body{
   background-color:#3E3947;
  } 
  #cd-vertical-nav {
   position: fixed;
   right: 40px;
   top: 50%;
   bottom: auto;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   z-index: 200;
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav li {
  text-align: right;
  list-style:none;
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  /* prevent weird movements on hover when you use a CSS3 transformation -   webkit browsers */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav a:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav a span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
  -o-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav a:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav a:hover .cd-label {
  opacity: 1;
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav a.is-selected .cd-dot {
  background-color: white;
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav .cd-dot {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d88683;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav .cd-label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: .4em .5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  }

    header {
              background: #f0f0f0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 86px;
              position: fixed; /* This helps in moving the navigation bar across the whole screen */
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              z-index: 100; /* So that it comes to the top of all the other elements */
              opacity: 1;
            }
            #logo {  /* Very good way of using/positioning the image or the logo */ 
              margin: 20px;
              float: left;
              width: 200px;
              height: 60px;
              background: url(//static1.squarespace.com/static/5278d304e4b085eb5a856b0f/t/528e5734e4b036f36b316a4a/1426667739619/?format=400w) no-repeat center;
            }
             nav { /* Note, here the nav is floated to the right and below each li is floated to the left */
              float: right;
              padding: 0px 30px 0px 0;
            }
             ul {
              list-style: none; 
            }
            nav ul li {
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;
                padding: 20px;
            }
            nav ul li a {
                font-weight: bold;
                color: black;
            }
            nav ul li a:hover {
                color: #808080;
            }
           nav ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
/*  position: absolute;*/
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 68px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul li ul li { 
  background: #fff; 
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  padding: 15% 40%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
/*nav ul li ul li a {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}*/
nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
            .current {
                color: #808080;
            }
                
/*********************************RIGHT SIDE    *************************************/

    </style>
 
</head>
<body onload="call()">
    
    <header>
            <a href="#" id="logo"></a>                       

            <nav>
                <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="current">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRODUCT</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Illustrations</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">CLIENTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header> 
    
    <div id="cd-vertical-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a data-number="1" href="#section1" class="is-selected">
                <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                <span class="cd-label">Intro</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-number="2" href="#section2" class="">
                <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                <span class="cd-label">About</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-number="3" href="#section3" class="">
                <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                <span class="cd-label">Features</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-number="4" href="#section4" class="">
                <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                <span class="cd-label">Portfolio</span>
            </a>
        </li>        
    </ul>
</div>

    <section id="section1">
        <h1>section1 starts here</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

    </section>

    <section id="section2">
        <h1>section2 starts here</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>        

    </section>

    <section id="section3">
        <h1>section3 starts here</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>   
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>  
    </section>
    
    <section id="section4">
        <h1>section4 starts here</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>   
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```